# How to adapt Apple singleton pattern for accessing SQLite database?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, singleton

Has anyone developed a singleton for accessing SQLite db? I know that there are other options like Core Data but, in my case, I need SQLite. I have looked at Apple provided singleton creation code ([here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW32)) but the thing is SQLite database "stuff" is not an object, it is "typedef struct sqlite3". So currently, I'm doubting how should I adapt this code for being singleton. Any suggestions, please :)

UPDATE: I have looked at FMDB framework for SQLite that does all stuff but it doesn't implement singleton. I mean, access methods are instance not class methods. If I need to call the SQL statements from different my code places I need to pass a pointer around instead of calling some shared instance class method :( So, the question remains open.

Comment: Using a singleton for things like a database is generally not a good idea in terms of code reuse, coupling, etc. Even Apple's Core Data guidelines explicity tell you to prefer depedency injection. Just an FYI.

Comment: I wouldn't agree on that, especially in term of code reuse. For example, in every place of my code, I want to get handler to database and to throw SQL like "[sharedDatabaseInstance executeQuery:sql];". Now, if I will go the other way without singleton then I will have to repeat 2 db init and open statements for every sql statement I want to pass.

Comment: Any of your view controllers etc. that require the database should have a property which is set by its parent, that's dependency injection. You ask for what you need, rather than going out to get it. But that's a design issue and I'm not necessarily telling you to change what you are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use FMDB, it is one of good wrapper libraries around for SQLite3.

See details about FMDB here http://www.ioslib.com/library/data/fmdb/

Comment: I got my singleton working with FMDB. I just wrapped FMDatabase class into apple recommended singleton class and everything went OK.